# Sequence/Series of $\frac{\log|\cos(n\pi x)|}{n}$ for irrational $x$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm pretty sure the limit of this sequence goes to $0$ and also that its series converges, but I'm not sure how to show it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's not true for $x$ very transcendental so it has approximations $|x-\frac{p_n}{2q_n}| \le \frac{1}{10^{q_n}}$ for example, with $p_n$ odd going to infinity and you can construct those easily by having very large blocks of zeros which increase exponentially in size between significant digits in the decimal representation; you should look into the Mahler classification of transcendentals for details; result true for algebraic irrational $x$ sure; by uniform distribution mod $1$ the series never converges since all terms are negative and most numerators bounded away from zero

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Also, a question -- following your suggestion to look into Mahler's classification is my first exposure to classifying transcendentals. I know that the algebraic numbers are countable, but is there any hope for this sequence going to 0 (or series converging, I'm not picky about which of those two results holds) almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$? What tools do you need to compare Lebesgue measure of various subsets of transcendentals?

Also, can you elaborate on your construction -- how do I know I can get arbitrary-size zero blocks in range of cos?

Comment: I will explicit the construction in an answer in a few hours when I get home and at the computer as it's a pain to type equations on the phone and I will look into some references on transcendentals classification, but my intuition is that the set where convergence fails is very sparse since you need to have the cosine very very (exponentially or better) close to odd half Pi's infinitely many times so it may have measure zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $0< |\cos (n\pi x)| <1$ for $x$ irrational so the sequence above consists of strictly negative but finite numbers.

We will prove that

1: there are infinitely many $0<x<1$ irrational for which the sequence doesn't go to zero; all such are Liouville numbers (they have rational approximations $|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}| < \frac{1}{q_n^n}$, for all $n \ge 1$) hence under the [Mahler classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number) of transcendental numbers (which is a refinement of the degree of irrationality as it involves integral polynomials of arbitrary degree, while the measure of irrationality refers to linear polynomials) they are part of class $U$ which has Lebesgue measure zero, so the sequence above converges a.e. on $(0,1)$ hence on $\mathbb{R}$ by $1-$periodicity

2: the series which is formed by summing the terms of the sequence above, never converges for any irrational $x$ (and actually for any non integral $x$ as the sequence is obviously zero at integers, while it is periodic and non zero at other rationals) since the terms being all negative, it is easy to see that if $||\cos \pi x|-1|=a>0$ and there is a $k$ for which $||\cos k\pi x|-1| < \frac{a^2}{200}$, then $||\cos (k+1)\pi x|-1| > \frac{a}{100}$ so $\log |\cos (k+1)\pi x| < -\frac{a}{100}=-c, c>0$ , so keeping only all the terms with $||\cos m\pi x|-1| > \frac{a}{100}$ only, we immediately get if we exclude a $k$ we cannot exclude $k+1$ and that clearly implies the series diverges to $-\infty$ as the harmonic series goes to $\infty$.

Let's now prove claim 1:

Let $0<x<1$ irrational for which the sequence above doesn't converge to zero, which means there are $c>0, n_k \to \infty$ s.t. $\log |\cos n_k\pi x| < -cn_k$, which is the same as $|\cos n_k\pi x| < e^{-cn_k}$ or $|\sin (n_k\pi x-\frac{q\pi}{2})|< e^{-cn_k}$ for all odd $q$.

Picking the unique odd $q=q_k$, s.t $|n_k\pi x-\frac{q_k\pi}{2}| < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and using the inequality:

$|\sin y| \ge a|y|, |y| \le \frac{\pi}{2}, a = \frac{2}{\pi}>0$, we get

$|n_k\pi x-\frac{q_k\pi}{2}| < \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-cn_k}$ or $|x-\frac{q_k}{2n_k}| < \frac{1}{2n_k}e^{-cn_k}$ and that obviously implies that $x$ is Liouville as for every $m$ we can pick $n_{k(m)}$ large enough s.t., $e^{-cn_{k(m)}} < \frac{1}{(2n_{k(m)})^m}$ etc

Conversely we will construct such an $x$ (and the construction will show that there are infinitely many choices and actually without too much trouble that there are uncountable many such, but by the above they have Lebesgue measure zero being Liouville numbers).

First we notice that if we can get an $x$ s.t. there are $p_n \to \infty$ odd and $q_n$, with $|x-\frac{p_n}{2q_n}| < 10^{-q_n}$, we easily get:

$|\sin (q_n\pi x-\frac{p_n\pi}{2})|< |q_n\pi x-\frac{p_n\pi}{2}| < q_n \pi 10^{-q_n}$, so

$|\cos q_n\pi x|< q_n \pi 10^{-q_n}$, so

$\log |\cos q_n\pi x| < -q_n \log 10 +\log q_n\pi$, so:

$\frac{\log |\cos q_n\pi x|}{q_n} < -\log 10 + \frac{\log q_n\pi}{q_n}$ and we showed that the sequence above doesn't converge to zero for this $x$

So for example pick an odd digit say $1$ and let $x$ start as $0.1...$, while $p_1=1, q_1=10$; then we put a bloc of (at least) $10^{10}$ zeroes followed by another odd digit (say again 1) and get $|x-\frac{1}{10}| < \frac{1}{10^{10}}$ which is (better) than our required first inequality; let $p_2, q_2$ given by the fraction we obtain by stopping $x$ here, $p_2$ odd, while $q_2$ is some power of $10$; we now add a block of at least $q_2^{10}$ zeroes and then an odd digit, say $1$ again and then by construction $|x-\frac{p_2}{q_2}| < \frac{1}{10^{q_2^{10}}}< \frac{1}{q_2^{10}}$, while we now get $p_3,q_3$ by stopping there and then we add a huge block (say at least $10^{q_3}$) zeroes and another odd digit etc; it is clear that we can use induction to define $x$ and our sequence so we are done showing there is one such $x$, while tinkering with the odd digit only and keeping the block lengths same we can construct as many such $x$ as there are sequences of odd digits (which are uncountable many by the usual diagonal argument). So we proved claim 1 too and we are done!

Comment: Thank you so much for walking me through this! Proving the a.e.-convergence of this sequence turned out to be much more complicated than I'd anticipated -- thank you for providing so many details.